# What does "LSB" mean when referring to executable files in the output of /bin/file?

Tags: executable, terminology, elf, file-format

I have found the term *"**LSB** executable"* or *"**LSB** shared object"* in the output of the `file` command in Linux. For example:

```
$ file /bin/ls
/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=4637713da6cd9aa30d1528471c930f88a39045ff, stripped
```

What does "LSB" mean in this context?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

“LSB” here stands for “least-significant byte” (first), as opposed to “MSB”, “most-significant byte”. It means that the binary is little-endian.

`file` [determines this](https://github.com/file/file/blob/4264364d4a46d632ceb095e8cef56339f592931d/magic/Magdir/elf#L305) from the sixth byte of the [ELF header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#File_header).

Comment: The other answer stated something completely different... Linux Standard Base.... Why is there confusion regarding this subject? I think you are probably right. It sounds like a more reasonable explanation.

Comment: There is confusion because “LSB” is an acronym covering different meanings. It can mean “Linux Standard Base” in other contexts; however in `file`’s output it means “least-significant byte” (as evidenced by the source code I linked to).

Comment: Many acronyms mean many different things. However my question was not: "What does LSB mean?" , but a more specific one regarding strictly executable files in ELF format.

Comment: Yes, exactly; I don’t think your question is unclear. However many people will just stop at “LSB” and reply “Linux Standard Base”.

Comment: I expect the confusion stems from a few things. 1. Writing "LSB" on it's own to indicate little endian is pretty unusual. 2. The Linux standards base standardised quite a bit about modern linux systems. 3. Most Linux users have probabblly never used a big-endian Linux system.

Comment: I've spent years thinking that the output meant the other LSB. The 'file' maintainers really need to change their output to something more obvious, like LE/BE.